# Matrix decomposition tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

There are three very common tags related to matrix decomposition/factorization, namely *diagonalization, svd* and *jordan normal form*.

I've seen some questions related to other matrix decompositions, namely $QR$ decomposition, Cholesky decomposition, Schur decomposition and $LU$ decomposition.

I would like to create a tag called *matrix decomposition* and have it included as synonyms the following terms: *matrix factorization, $LU$ decomposition, $LU$ factorization, $QR$ decomposition, $QR$ factorization, Cholesky decomposition, Cholesky factorization,  Schur decomposition, Schur factorization* and *triangularization*.

I would like input on wether to include *diagonalization, svd* and *jordan normal form* in the synonym list above.

Side questions: do the tags need to exist for it to be possible to be included as synonyms? If there is no question tagged *$LU$ decomposition*, is it possible to include *$LU$ decomposition* as a synonym? If it isn't possible, why not allow us such prophylactic measures?

Comment: agreed. +1 for the last suggestion.

Comment: Maybe in analogy to [simplicial-stuff] we can have [matricial-stuff] too? :-)

Comment: To the side question: it is possible to create a synonym from scratch, but you need more rep than the 2500 required to synonymize an existing tag. [See here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12307/mo-mse-tag-incompatibility#comment48969_12325). Of course, a mod can create a tag synonym at once. // I don't think that svd and diagonalization should be merged into an umbrella tag. // The multitude of synonyms you propose looks excessive to me. For pretty much any tag one come up with half a page of terms that could appear within the tag; it does not mean we need so many synonyms.